# Visual studio не видит заголовочный файл, хотя он есть

Tags: opengl

в папке D:/Microsoft Visual Studio/VC98/Include/GL лежат три файла - GL.H, GLU.H, glut.h
компилятор нормально реагирует на

```
#include "GL/GLU.H"
#include "GL/GL.H"
```

но в ответ на `#include "GL/glut.h"` выдаёт: `"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glut.h': No such file or directory"`

поиск по интернету не помогает
пробовал даже варианты вроде `<GL/glut.h>, <GL/glut>, <glut.h>, <glut>, "glut.h"`

Файлы GLU.H, GL.H уже были в той папке, а вот glut.h я добавил сам.
ОС = Windows XP, среда Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0.
проект запускается из директории D:/Microsoft Visual Studio/MyProjects/3

Не знаю, имеет ли какое-то отношение к делу, но остальные части инструкции по установке OpenGL я сделал - `glut.dll` и `glut32.dll` добавил в windows/system32 и прописал в project->settings->link, а `glut.lib` и `glut32.lib` добавил в `D:/Microsoft Visual Studio/VC98/Lib`

Правда, при регистрации `regsrv32 glut32.dll` выдаёт ошибку `glut32.dll была загружена, но найти точку входа для DllRegisterServer не удалось`, а при регистрации `regsrv32 glut.dll` выдаёт ошибку `ошибка при вызове LoadLibrary ("glut.dll") - не найден указанный модуль`.

драйвера видеокарты поддерживают только OpenGL 1.4, а я устанавливаю dll/lib/h версии 3.7 - возможно отсюда ошибка DllRegisterServer, но не должно ведь это всё влиять на то, чтобы студия просто нашла .h файл! как заставить студию проиндексировать свои папки по-новой?

Comment: Добавлять файл в каталог с хедерами компилятора — не самая лучшая идея, честное слово.

Попробуйте полный rebuild, возможно, где-то информация закеширована.

Но лучше — положите ваш дополнительный хедер отдельно, и настройте include directories для вашего проекта.

Comment: регистрировать эти библиотеки точно не нужно.

Comment: Возможны проблемы с разрешениями на файл.

Comment: спасибо, у меня зачем-то на компьютере было несколько папок с Visual Studio, и когда я залез в tools=>options=>directories, то понял, что Visual Studio настроен на работу не с той папкой, которой я думал...