# Visual Studio не видит заголовочный файл

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Не могу понять, почему файл заголовочный подключен, но при сборке Visual Studio его не видит.

переделываю библиотеку с 32 битов в 64 бита.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас на первом скриншоте явно видно, что `master_dll_defines.h` лежит в каких-то `..\..\headers`. В настройках проекта на втором скриншоте я у вас никакого `headers` не вижу. В чем смысл второго скриншота, если по нему не видно, есть ли там эти `headers` или нет? Почему вы не раскрыли список каталогов перед тем как делать скриншот?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, у вас VS не настроен для работы с данной папкой. Подобной вопрос уже [поднимался.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264055/visual-studio-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)
Проверьте директории в tools > options > directories.

Либо в свойствах проекта в параметре Additional > Include Directories необходимо указать путь ко всем папкам  (Settings > Configuration Properties > C\C++ > General).

Comment: tools > options > directories.  не может быть ибо у меня  открыт только одни проект . Settings > Configuration Properties > C\C++ > General обновил вопрос там как раз так и сделано

Comment: @timob256, попробуйте указать другую директорию

Answer (score 2):

В треугольных скобках в `#include` указываются стандартные хедеры реализации (т.е. "системные" заголовки). Я никогда не слышал о таком стандартном хедере, как `master_dll_defines.h`. Почему у вас вдруг использованы треугольные скобки для включения этого заголовка? Это относится и к остальным заголовкам со странными названиями.

Если вы хотите, чтобы заголовочный файл искался в путях, настроенных в локальных установках вашего проекта, используйте `""`, а не треугольные скобки.

Comment: Поменял, как не работало так и не работает

Comment: @timob256: Так а путь прописан? У вас на скриншоте явно видно, что `master_dll_defines.h` лежит в `..\..\headers`. В настройках я у вас никакого `headers` не вижу.

Comment: Кажется так, кроме тех случаев где это не так чуть больше чем полностью :) Как раз треугольные скобки используются при поиске в путях, а обычные кавычки для поиска по обсалютному пути. Автор может добавить собственные директории в пути компилятора (проекта), и тогда это будет работоспособно.

Comment: @NewView Возможно, но это не повод злоупотреблять. Треугольные скобки предназначены для хедеров "известных компилятору". Для пользовательских хедеров - только кавычки.

Comment: Как стиль, согласен и поддерживаю